# Telegram channels on Ubuntu touch (App and Scope) with OTA-11

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, webapps, scopes, telegram

How can i see Telegram channels in the Telegram App for ubuntu-touch or in the Telegram Scope for this Operating System?
E.g. They don't appear there in a Meizu Pro5 mobile with OTA-11.

Comment: I have found a work around to see Telegram's channels by using other app, the "webTelegram" app.

Answer (score 4):

The feature is not supported, yet.
Maybe it helps hitting "affects me" on https://bugs.launchpad.net/telegram-app/+bug/1535340.

A workaround is using the [WebTelegram](https://uappexplorer.com/app/webtelegram.markcortbass) App.